# Proving a rather simple theorem in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I'm trying, without success, some experiments with dependently typed programming in Haskell. My idea is to express some sort of weakening property on finite mappings. The whole code is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables      #-}

module Exp where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Equality
import GHC.TypeLits

 data Exp (env :: [(Symbol,*)]) (a :: *) where
   Val :: Int -> Exp env Int
   Var :: (KnownSymbol s, Lookup s env ~ 'Just a) => Proxy s -> Exp env a

 data HList (xs :: [(Symbol,*)]) where
    Nil :: HList '[]
    (:*) :: KnownSymbol s => (Proxy s, Exp ('(s,a) ': xs) a) -> HList xs -> HList ('(s,a) ': xs)

 infixr 5 :*

 type family If (b :: Bool) (l :: k) (r :: k) :: k where
    If 'True  l r = l
    If 'False l r = r

 type family Lookup (s :: Symbol) (env :: [(Symbol,*)]) :: Maybe * where
    Lookup s '[]             = 'Nothing
    Lookup s ('(t,a) ': env) = If (s == t) ('Just a) (Lookup s env)

 look :: (Lookup s xs ~ 'Just a, KnownSymbol s) => Proxy s -> HList xs -> Exp xs a
 look s ((s',p) :* rho) = case sameSymbol s s' of
                            Just Refl -> p
                            Nothing   -> look s rho
```

GHC complains that call `look s rho` doesn't have type `Exp xs a`, since recursive call is done on a finite environment `rho` with less entries than the original one. I believe that the solution is to weaken `Exp xs a` to `Exp ('(s,b) ': xs) a`. Here goes my try to weaken expressions:

```
weak :: (Lookup s xs ~ 'Just a
        , KnownSymbol s
        , KnownSymbol s'
        , (s == s') ~ 'False) => Exp xs a -> Exp ('(s', b) ': xs) a
weak (Val n) = Val n
weak (Var s) = Var (Proxy :: Lookup s ('(s', b) ': xs) ~ 'Just a => Proxy s)
```

and GHC responds with a type ambiguity error:

```
Could not deduce: Lookup s0 xs ~ 'Just a
  from the context: (Lookup s xs ~ 'Just a,
                     KnownSymbol s,
                     KnownSymbol s',
                     (s == s') ~ 'False)
    bound by the type signature for:
               weak :: (Lookup s xs ~ 'Just a, KnownSymbol s, KnownSymbol s',
                        (s == s') ~ 'False) =>
                       Exp xs a -> Exp ('(s', b) : xs) a
```

I'm aware that such weakening can be easily implemented if we use typed De Bruijn indexes to represent variables. My question is: Is possible to implement it for names instead of indexes? If so, how it can be done?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, so: In `look` you have `Lookup s ('(s', b) : xs) ~ Just a`. In the `Nothing` branch GHC doesn't know how to build `Lookup s xs ~ Just a` when you recursively `look`. You could prove the law of the excluded middle `Natty n -> Natty m -> Either (n :~: m) (Not (n :~: m))` (for the sake of discussion I'm switching from `Symbol`s to `Nat`s and singleton `Natty`s because opaque `Symbol`s have no singleton partner), where `Not a = a -> Void`. Then in the `Right` branch you can use said evidence to eliminate impossible cases when building the smaller context.

Comment: My instinct here is to walk away from all this theorem-proving, though. Instead try an automated proof search for the aforementioned typed indices using the class system. `class EL x xs where el :: El x xs` and a pair of instances which attempt to match `x` against the head of the list. You might need to use [this trick](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap)

Comment: Implementing `LookupIndex` instead of `Lookup` -- essentially converting your names to deBruijn indices -- would probably work and should be pretty simple, and would still let you expose a public interface that was in terms of names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is explained by [Benjamin Hodgson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson) in the comments. For this to solve you just need a more typed `sameSymbol`:

```
sameOrNotSymbol :: (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b)
                => Proxy a -> Proxy b -> Either ((a == b) :~: 'False) (a :~: b)
sameOrNotSymbol s s' = maybe (Left $ unsafeCoerce Refl) Right $ sameSymbol s s'
```

Then `look` can be defined as (assuming `weak` is proved):

```
look :: (Lookup s xs ~ 'Just a, KnownSymbol s)
     => Proxy s -> HList xs -> Exp (DropWhileNotSame (s, a) xs) a
look s ((s',p) :* rho) = case sameOrNotSymbol s s' of
  Left  Refl -> weak s $ look s rho
  Right Refl -> p
```

The ambiguity error you get is due to the fact that `s` is mentioned in the constraints, but is not determined anywhere. This is easy to fix — just provide a `Proxy s`:

```
weak :: forall s s' xs a b. (KnownSymbol s
        , KnownSymbol s'
        , (s == s') ~ 'False)
     => Proxy s -> Exp xs a -> Exp ('(s', b) ': xs) a
weak s (Val n) = Val n
weak s (Var t) = ...
```

But here we encounter a problem that is much harder to fix. What if a symbol stored in that `Exp xs a` is the same as `s'` — the symbol prepended to the list? Returning `Var t` would be incorrect in this case, because the meaning of `Var t` is changed: it no longer denotes a symbol somewhere in the middle of the list — it's in the head now. And it's not type correct, since that requires `a` and `b` to be the same type. So this version type checks:

```
weak :: forall s s' xs a a. (KnownSymbol s
        , KnownSymbol s'
        , (s == s') ~ 'False)
     => Proxy s -> Exp xs a -> Exp ('(s', a) ': xs) a
weak s (Val n) = Val n
weak s (Var t) = case sameOrNotSymbol t (Proxy :: Proxy s') of
  Left  Refl -> Var t
  Right Refl -> Var (Proxy :: Proxy s')
```

but the one you desire does not. "But we know that a stored symbol cannot be `s'`, because this situation is explicitly refuted by the way `look` is defined" — you might say. Good luck proving it.

Just use de Bruijn indices, really.

Comment: Thanks @user3237465! Using your code, I've managed to get a satisfactory solution!

Comment: @Rodrigo Ribeiro, could you show it or describe shortly?

Comment: Sorry... I thought that what I changed was correct, but after a little testing I found a missing bug. I'm still have some troubles on this. Anyway, thanks for your partial solution.